# How to map a list of numbers to the list of their deltas in Scala?

Tags: scala, list-comprehension

Suppose I have a list of numbers. How to convert the list to a list of their "deltas" -- the pairwise differences of the subsequent numbers?

For example: Given `List(5, 2, 1, 1)` I would like to get `List(3, 1, 0)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct answer is

```
(xs, xs drop 1).zipped.map(_-_)
```

And it does not even explode when you pass it an empty or single-digit list.

Comment: Agreed, this is the briefest and also has the best performance.

Answer (score 10):

```
List(5,2,1,1).sliding(2).map(pair => pair(0) - pair(1))
```

Comment: Be aware that this explodes when the input list contains only one element.

Answer (score 5):

Two other possible solutions:

```
list.zip(list.drop(1)).map { case (x, y) => x - y }

// in case you don't like the extractor method of dealing with Tuples
list.zip(list.drop(1)).map(p => p._1 - p._2)
```

Comment: Note that you can use `list.tail` instead of `list.drop(1)` (but `tail` does not play nicely with `Nil`). Anyway, +1.

Comment: I think I'll stick with `.drop(1)` for the proper handling of Nil.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 3):

It's not dreadfully efficient (creating a two element list for every pair of adjacent numbers), but

```
list.sliding(2).map(x=>(x(0)-x(1)))
```

should give you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

For everyone that prefers for-comprehensions over maps, doesn't mind extractors and likes to name intermediate results:

```
for (List(current, next) <- list.sliding(2);
     delta = current - next)
  yield delta
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursive way :

```
scala> def calcDeltas(l:List[Int]):List[Int] = l match {
     | case Nil => Nil
     | case x::Nil => Nil
     | case x::y::Nil => (x-y)::Nil
     | case x::y::tail => (x-y)::calcDeltas(y::tail)
     | }
```